# How to change the size of o notification in zk framework?

Tags: zk

How to change the size (width, height) of a notification in zk framework ?

```
Clients.showNotification();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is **no** (built in) way of doing that. I just checked the ZK sources and it basically comes down to this:

```
public AuNotification(String msg, String type, Page page, Component ref, 
        String position, int duration, boolean closable) {
    super("showNotification", new Object[] { 
            msg, type, page.getUuid(), ref, position, null, duration, closable });
}
```

So the client-side engine is told to display the notification, no sizes involved.